# doing a self taught online course with python. need help trouble shooting this

Tags: python

I need a good place to get up to date syntax for the newest version of python. can anyone help trouble shoot this? brand new to programming. the program I am running just keeps coming back as "hey" and not Hey with the name I enter in after it.

code:

```
x = input('Enter name:')
print("hey ") + x
```

Comment: You can read the official python docs for getting up to date syntax for the newest version: https://docs.python.org/3

Comment: Documentation can be found at Python.org, and Google could have told you that without posting here. Is your Google broken? It's not a complicated search; *python documentation* finds it very quickly.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to upload the code there :)

Comment: Please do *not post code a an image, or as a link to an image*. Source code *is text*. Post it as formatted text in the question itself. Also, please familiarize yourself with [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

From the image you uploaded, it's possible to see the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

The problem is when you close the `print` call before the `+ x`. So, what python is trying to do is add the result of `print("hey")` (which is the NoneType part) to the variable `x` (type string)

This version should work:

```
x = input('Enter name:')
print("hey " + x)
```

On the above version, you are creating a string that is made up of the literal `hey` and the content of `x`. This newly created string will be passed to the `print` call